# variable of variable value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my requirement the list is dynamically creating with collection of dictionaries with different columns for each time. So every time what I need to print will be different based on the some logic.

If I create **if ..else** statement for each case I can print what ever I want.

Here I have too many cases so I dont want to write that many **if ...esle** statements just to print.

Instead of that I want to read what I need to print from a config file and print the actual value.

Example: 
list1=[{'name': 'xyz', 'age' : 22, 'place' : 'huj'}, {'name' : 'hjhd", 'age' : 44, 'place' : 'wer'}]

want to print name and age columns

```
the following code will do my work.
if id == 1:
    for i in list1:
        i['name']+","+i['age']
elif id == 2:
    for i in list1:
        i['account']+","+i['spend']
elif id == 3:
    for i in list1:
        i['percentage']+","+i['rank']
```

I just want to write only one if else statement. Since I have more than 100 cases.

Instead of writing these many if else statements is there any other way I can handle this by using ConfigParser or any thing else.

Answer (score 5):

You can use print formatting like

```
for entry in list1:
    print("{name}, {age}  ({place})".format(**entry))
```

Comment: Real classy! Good one!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
x = ["name", "age"]
for i in list1:
    for k in x:
        print list1[i][k]
```

Comment: I would have answered the same, though the question is really unclear :)

Comment: I agree.  By "variable" I assume that `x` is actually programatically set somewhere... If it's fixed then @Hugh's answer is probably better.

Comment: Scott - I store in a file what all the things need to be print. In file i['name']+","+i['age']  -- will be there I read and store in a variable and I want to print that

Comment: ah.  You want something like this then?: `for entry in list1: print open("{name},{age}".format(**entry)).read()`

Answer (score 0):

I am also pretty confused by the question but here is another option

```
list1=[{'name': 'xyz', 'age' : 22, 'place' : 'huj'}, {'name' : 'hjhd", 'age' : 44, 'place' : 'wer'}]

key1 = "name"
key2 = "age"
key3 = "place"

x = [li[key1] + li[key2] + li[key3] for li in list1]
print x
```

Comment: Deric, In my requirement the list is dynamically created with collection of dictionaries with different columns. So every time what I need to print will be different based on the some logic. If I create if ..else statement for each case I can print what ever I want. Here I have too many cases so I dont want to write that many if ...esle statements just to print. Instead of that I want to read what I need to print from a config file and print the actual value. For example here I want to print name and age. The parameters I want to read from config file and print the actual value.